# Check if a weekday is between two weekdays

Tags: php, algorithm

I have recently been stuck on what I think should be a fairly simple problem.

Basically I have weekdays represented as a number (1-7) representing Monday to Sunday.

I need a function that has this prototype:

```
function weekday_between(weekday, start_weekday, end_weekday) {
    //if the weekday is between start and end then return true, otherwise return false
    ...
}
```

The main issue I am having is when the start_weekday is greater than the end_weekday, since I don't think you can just rely on a nested if statement (?).

For example:

```
weekday_between(2, 1, 3) //return true
weekday_between(1, 7, 2) //return true, the hard part
weekday_between(2, 7, 1) //return false
weekday_between(6, 7, 1) //return false
```

The project is in php but pseudocode is fine, or even just a point in the right direction.

Comment: Any weekday is always between any other two weekdays... :o)

Comment: weekdays is between 2 weekdays as deceze mentioned...so u have to use b/w 2 & 4(including 2 & 4)

Comment: @PatrickGalbraith Fair enough. I only ask because usually when people come with the needed prototype but an empty function body, it's an assignment.

Comment: @deceze and Anish: is Friday between Tuesday and Thursday? (may be between Thursday and Tuesday, but come on... you are smart enough to understand the question)

Comment: @J.B Yes, between the Tuesday of the same week and Thursday of the following week. In other words, to make this condition really accurate, you need to stipulate that the start and end days must also not be further apart than 1 week. :o)

Comment: @deceze: yep! the function requested has start and end days as parameters... you seem to be over-complicating... it's just a matter of wanting to know if Wednesday is between Monday and Friday, or if Saturday is between Friday and Monday... if I schedule that I will work for you "from Tuesday to Friday"... what would you understand from this?

Comment: @deceze yeah that is correct. Sorry I should have said that in the op.

Comment: @J.B I think your tongue-in-cheek-o-meter needs a little tuning. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function weekday_between(weekday, start_weekday, end_weekday) {
    if (end_weekday < start_weekday)
        return (weekday > start_weekday) OR (weekday < end_weekday);
    else
        return (weekday > start_weekday) AND (weekday < end_weekday);
}
```

Comment: It is a fairly simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here: $b = between value, $s = start value, and $e = end value.

```
function weekday_between($s, $b, $e){
  if($s>$e) $s -=7;
  return (($b>$s)&&($b<$e));
}
```

Yes I changed the order of your function arguments...doesn't it make more sense to have the between value...between!

Comment: Quoting OP: `weekday_between(1, 7, 2) //return true, the hard part`

Comment: thx @deceze - modified to debase start date if it's larger. I think this covers all edge cases... if not, I'll send my answer to the purgatory!